# Phpstorm bookmarks/breakpoints are not showing up in favorites tool

Tags: phpstorm

According to this: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/favorites-tool-window.html

> The lists of bookmarks and breakpoints are filled in automatically, as
>   the new bookmarks or breakpoints are added.

However when I tried adding bookmarks and debug breakpoints, they dont get added to the favorites tool window.

What should I do so that the list of bookmarks and breakpoints will actually display in the favorites window automatically just as the documentation claims?

Comment: This should automatically happen.

Comment: What version (rather, build number) of PhpStorm do you have there (Help | About)? Works OK in 129.240. If you are using v6.0 then just wait for 6.0.1 to be released.

Comment: @LazyOne I'm using 127.100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality (favorites, bookmarks and breakpoints all in single window) was not actually shipped in v6.0 final (build 127.100). But it is available in upcoming **v6.0.1** (129.xxx.branch)